# Can I please get the proofs for different trajectories of a satellite when projected at different velocities?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics, satellites

I recently came across a question about the trajectories of satellites, I have tried many resources for the proofs but couldn't find them.
For example, a satellite will have an elliptical orbit if (orbital velocity<given velocity<escape velocity) and a hyperbolic trajectory if given velocity is more than escape velocity. So can I please get the mathematical proofs for these.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proof for elliptical orbits](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/553917/)

Answer (score 0):

There is a very nice proof for this in [this StackExchange answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/553978/330601), working with Newton's second law in polar coordinates.